# Build a read-only PDF with Webshot/phantomjs

Tags: javascript, pdf, phantomjs

I have a short question.

Is it possible to create a read-only PDF with webshot/phantomjs and if so, how?

With read-only I mean, in order to change anything in the pdf, you need a password.

Thanks!

Comment: Um pdf files themselves don't have any level of security like that. You want to look at the way you access the pdf file.

Comment: Pdf is just a print document format. So if it's read access on your site anyone can download the pdf and alter their local copy but that doesn't mean they can change the one on your server. To change the one on a server you would want to create an authenticated https post request so that it requires a password that just replaces the file in the server.

Comment: And can you be specific on what you're using it for is it for a web page that you're creating using phantom or are you creating a application based on phantom